# cryptocoin address generation

Tags: ruby, bitcoin, dogecoin-api

Recently have been looking at crypto currencies, mostly Bitcoin and Dogecoin. I'm using this [source](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) for my project. I've got Bitcoin to work perfectly, and since the Bitcoin gem did not have native support for Dogecoin I had to self-implement it.

Also noticed that another githubber had opened tried to implement [dogecoin](https://github.com/indirect/bitcoin-ruby/commit/36d6ae7057b47c49ba924ee69ca461b3254ce675#commitcomment-4923865) support, which as of now did not generating address correctly.

The problem seems to  be in this particular line. (corresponding to the format of the crypto address)

```
:address_version => "30"

:address_version = PUBKEY_ADDRESS in base58.h
```

[base58.h](https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master/src/base58.h)

`PUBKEY_ADRESS` contains value `30`.

Specifying this particular number will give address beginning with letter 'L' (litecoin address), where Dogecoin requires 'D'.

Does this have anything to do with Doge using scrypt, I have no technical expertise in this field. How do I go about generating dogecoin pubkey/private key pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`30` in decimal will give you a address begins with a letter `D`

`30` in hexadecimal (`48` in decimal) will give you a address begins with letter `L`

I think that `bitcoin-ruby` first changes `PUBKEY_ADDRESS` from hexa to decimal so `:address_version` should be `1E` (`30` in decimal)

Comment: Ah, such a trivial thing din't realize this.